# Very Simple Insert From Select Not Working?

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, insert, bulkinsert

All I did was remake a table and add null constrants and default values on columns:

Original Table structure (now renamed):

```
CREATE TABLE "CARTWEIGHTS_old" (
  EntryTime DateTime, 
  Employee TEXT, 
  PLUGS NUMERIC,
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  PO NUMERIC, 
  FUSER INTEGER, 
  REMAN INTEGER, 
  OEM INTEGER, 
  DIGITEK INTEGER, 
  LEXMARK INTEGER, 
  PDW INTEGER, 
  TRASH INTEGER, 
  CART TEXT,
  "Voided" BOOL NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0
)
```

The New table:

```
CREATE TABLE CARTWEIGHTS (
  EntryTime DateTime,
  Employee TEXT,
  PLUGS NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  PO NUMERIC,
  FUSER INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0, 
  REMAN INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
  OEM INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0, 
  DIGITEK INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
  LEXMARK INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0, 
  PDW INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
  TRASH INTEGER NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
  CART TEXT, 
  "Voided" BOOL NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0
)
```

then when I try to run:

```
insert into CARTWEIGHTS 
select * from CARTWEIGHTS_old
```

the CARTWEIGHTS Table is not updated with the info. SQLite also does not give me any errors.

Comment: What select * from CARTWEIGHTS_old returns?

Comment: @AndreDuarte It returns exactly what is expected, all the data in the table...

Comment: Does SQLite supports this type of operation? It's weird that it didnt returns any erros ...

Comment: @AndreDuarte Yes, And I have successfully used it before [Here Is The SQLite Insert Info](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) And just to test I made an exact copy of the table structure, named it test and ran `insert into test select * from CARTWEIGHTS` and it worked...

Comment: There is any sequence associated with the primary key?

Comment: @AndreDuarte Thats the answer I switched the insert to not include the ID column and it worked. I just wish it would have thrown the error...

Comment: Yeah. Thats weird. Maybe it's a SQLite config. But at least you solved it.

Comment: @AndreDuarte I'll mark as accepted answer if you'd like to add it as an answer, you could show the final statement being `INSERT INTO "CARTWEIGHTS" 

"EntryTime","Employee","PLUGS","PO","FUSER","REMAN","OEM","DIGITEK","LEXMARK","PDW","TRASH","CART","Voided"

SELECT "EntryTime","Employee","PLUGS","PO","FUSER","REMAN","OEM","DIGITEK","LEXMARK","PDW","TRASH","CART","Voided" FROM "CARTWEIGHTS_old"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with de sequence generator for ID. Try not inserting your PK in the destination table:

```
INSERT INTO "CARTWEIGHTS"  
"EntryTime","Employee","PLUGS","PO","FUSER","REMAN","OEM","DIGITEK","LEXMARK",
"P‌​DW","TRASH","CART","Voided"  
SELECT "EntryTime","Employee","PLUGS","PO","FUSER","REMAN","OEM","DIGITEK","LEXMARK",
"P‌​DW","TRASH","CART","Voided" FROM "CARTWEIGHTS_old"
```